# I have an error when I try to run a maven project in netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, java-ee-6, data-access-layer

I have an error when I try to run a maven project in netbeans

> Error : Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "D:\Programing\Java\WorkSpace\senior pro\seniorDAL"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.cmd" -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 install

Answer (score 0):

DO you have installing jdk?

Although this problem can be fixed by installing jdk

The problem also occurs in version jdk Fixing installing other version